# How to insert product in cart through rest api provided by woocommerce?

Tags: php, wordpress, cordova, woocommerce

i am converting a woocommerce store into phonegap app. Now i am stuck. how to add product into cart and display cart into the phonegap app. So how to do it with the help of rest api.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 15, accepted):

[This](https://github.com/woothemes/woocommerce/issues/8909) related GitHub issue might help.

It seems that there will be no API for sessions or cart. It is suggested to use the order endpoint if you want to use the API. There is a way to add a product to the cart without the API though, you can do that with an URL like: `http://yourproducturl.com/checkout/?add-to-cart=%ID%`.

Comment: and what about removing, listing etc? do we have to write the endpoints ourselves?

Comment: Did you ever figure out how to add and remove line items from your order?

Comment: @MichaelLynch You can edit an order via the official API. See http://woocommerce.github.io/woocommerce-rest-api-docs/#update-an-order

Comment: @VictorFerreira There is no official API for sessions or cart. I'm not sure any 3rd party library that offers that, otherwise you need to implement this yourself. But you can dig into the WooCommerce code base to see how it is done.

Comment: what about the response ? and where it will add then

Comment: Thans a lot bro

Comment: Thanks, it works like a charm. But I couldn't figure out how u can add multiple products?

Comment: this doesn work with multiple products and with add-ons. I've been able to add using json, but not with add-ons.

Answer (score 10):

on Wordpress 5.4.1, Woocommerce 4.1.0
you have endpoints under this namespace for managing cart and others

`https://yoursite.com/wp-json/wc/store/`

check it out.

Comment: it seems the cart API is added in the new version but there is no documentation for how to use it (add product or remove product) unfortunately

Comment: you can add to cart, or remove from cart, or even apply coupon, when you open yours like this example https://yoursite.com/wp-json/wc/store/ expand the endpoints, you'll see the allowed methods, and the payload expected.

Answer (score 8):

Some years later, we have a working REST API endpoint at `/wp-json/wc/store/cart/add-item`.

It requires a product or variant id and a quantity. It also requires a `X-WC-Store-API-Nonce` header that is set to what wordpress gives you when calling `wp_create_nonce('wc_store_api')`. You can even remove items with a negative quantity, neat.

Here is a working jQuery example for my variant id 378:

```
<script>
var _nonce = "<?php echo wp_create_nonce( 'wc_store_api' ); ?>";
$.ajax({
  type: 'POST',
  url: '/wp-json/wc/store/cart/add-item',
  dataType: 'json',
  headers: {
    'X-WC-Store-API-Nonce': _nonce
  },
  data: {
    id : 378,
    quantity: 1
  }
});
</script>
```

(Tested on WooCommerce 4.5.2, 4.6.1) ([Github thread](https://github.com/woocommerce/woocommerce-rest-api/issues/220#issuecomment-719960162))

Comment: Any idea on how to attach this cart to a customer that already exists? i.e customer id=5

Answer (score 3):

Just in case someone finds this, there is CoCart available in the meantime which solves OPs problem:
https://wordpress.org/plugins/cart-rest-api-for-woocommerce/